# How to match each line with regex in flutte?

Tags: regex, flutter

Hello I have a string like that

```
"
load
yes

test
2

10/05/2020
1
"
```

I search to extract each line like this

```
regex1 = load
regex2 = yes
regex3 = test
regex4 = 2
regex4 = 10/05/2020
regex5 = 1
```

But I search also to avoid if there is no match, for example I can have a case where i havn't 10/05/2020
so I can un a prédictive match as (10/05/2020).

I don't know also how many lines there will be, it can be more or less.

But structure is the same

```
X1
X2
space
X3
X4
space 
...
```

I don't found a regex tout isolate each X in différent group ou différent equation

Comment: `print(yourMultilineString.split('\n').where((line) => line.length > 0));`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a sophisticated regex for this, strictly speaking. You only have to split this by newline, in this case, any amount of newline.

The regex you need to split it by is `\n+`

Now if you do-

```dart
List<String> strList = str.split(new RegExp(r"\n+"));
```

Where `str` is-

```dart
String str = """load
yes


test
2

10/05/2020
1
""";
```

(**Note**: The `str` format itself is important, any extra newlines or whitespace will give you unwanted results)

You'll get the result-

> [load, yes, test, 2, 10/05/2020, 1]

Check out the demo here